# What does X-Apple-Store-Front means in Apple http headers?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I need get hot search keywords using apple API https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearchHints.woa/wa/trends, 
and set values {"X-Apple-Store-Front": "143465-19,30"} in http
headers, if i set "X-Apple-Store-Front" to "143465-19,30", the result is

```
{
    "header": {
        "label": "热门搜索"
    },
    "trendingSearches": [
        {
            "label": "蜜芽",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=%E8%9C%9C%E8%8A%BD"
        },
        {
            "label": "qq",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=qq"
        },
        {
            "label": "腾讯视频",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=%E8%85%BE%E8%AE%AF%E8%A7%86%E9%A2%91"
        },
        {
            "label": "微信",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=%E5%BE%AE%E4%BF%A1"
        },
        {
            "label": "爱奇艺",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=%E7%88%B1%E5%A5%87%E8%89%BA"
        },
        {
            "label": "淘宝",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=%E6%B7%98%E5%AE%9D"
        },
        {
            "label": "百度",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6"
        },
        {
            "label": "qq音乐",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=qq%E9%9F%B3%E4%B9%90"
        },
        {
            "label": "微博",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=%E5%BE%AE%E5%8D%9A"
        },
        {
            "label": "百度网盘",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&src=trending&term=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%BD%91%E7%9B%98"
        }
    ]
}
```

if i set "X-Apple-Store-Front" to "143465-19,29", the result will change.

```
{
    "header": {
        "label": "热门搜索"
    },
    "trendingSearches": [
        {
            "label": "铃声",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=%E9%93%83%E5%A3%B0"
        },
        {
            "label": "李荣浩",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=%E6%9D%8E%E8%8D%A3%E6%B5%A9"
        },
        {
            "label": "泰勒·斯威夫特",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=%E6%B3%B0%E5%8B%92%C2%B7%E6%96%AF%E5%A8%81%E5%A4%AB%E7%89%B9"
        },
        {
            "label": "像我这样的人",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=%E5%83%8F%E6%88%91%E8%BF%99%E6%A0%B7%E7%9A%84%E4%BA%BA"
        },
        {
            "label": "eminem",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=eminem"
        },
        {
            "label": "杨宗纬",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=%E6%9D%A8%E5%AE%97%E7%BA%AC"
        },
        {
            "label": "张碧晨",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=%E5%BC%A0%E7%A2%A7%E6%99%A8"
        },
        {
            "label": "刘若英",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=%E5%88%98%E8%8B%A5%E8%8B%B1"
        },
        {
            "label": "lady gaga",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=lady%20gaga"
        },
        {
            "label": "赵雷",
            "url": "https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=MusicPlayer&src=trending&term=%E8%B5%B5%E9%9B%B7"
        }
    ]
}
```

, pls tell me what does mean and how to use X-Apple-Store-Front, and the X-Apple-Store-Front mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THis `X-Apple-Store-Front` is a country code. For more info:
https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/linking-to-the-itunes-music-store/

Comment: Thank your help, "143465-19,30"   "143465" is a country code, and what does mean "19,30"?

Comment: @Yang I think it's related to the device. I'm trying to figure out myself

Comment: @CharltonProvatas any luck so far?

Answer (score 6):

`143465-19,29` means `CN store, zh-cn language, P84 platform`

It's `${storefrontID}-${languageVariationID},${platformID}`. More info [here](https://fann.im/blog/2018/05/15/app-store-front-code/). Language variations are explained a bit [here](https://ithink.ch/blog/2006/05/27/how_itunes_selects_the_storefront.html). Basically, if you leave off the `-${languageVariationID}`, you'll get a decent default for storefront's country.

If you want a non-default language, the language-variations are here:

```
{
  'pt-br': 15,
  'it-it': 7,
  'hi-in': 50,
  'ca-es': 42,
  'es-es': 8,
  'zh-tw': 18,
  'th-th': 35,
  'da-dk': 11,
  'fi-fi': 12,
  'en-gb': 2,
  'nl-nl': 10,
  'pl-pl': 20,
  'ro-ro': 39,
  'zh-cn': 19,
  'no-no': 14,
  'pt-pt': 24,
  'de-ch': 57,
  'uk-ua': 29,
  'en-us': 1,
  'vi-vi': 43,
  'sv-se': 17,
  'en-ca': 6,
  'fr-fr': 3,
  'sk-sk': 40,
  'zh-hk': 45,
  'hr-hr': 41,
  'en-au': 27,
  'ko-kr': 13,
  'tr-tr': 25,
  'el-gr': 23,
  'ms-my': 38,
  'id-id': 37,
  'cs-cz': 22,
  'hu-hu': 21,
  'fr-ca': 5,
  'es-mx': 28,
  'de-de': 4,
  'ru-ru': 16,
  'ja-jp': 9
}
```

The platform-ids available are these:

```
{
  K7: 20,
  P7: 21,
  K71: 23,
  P71: 24,
  K8: 25,
  P8: 26,
  P84: 29,
  K84: 30,
  Android: 31,
  Watch: 35,
  MacPodcasts1: 38
}
```

And the store-ids are here:

```
{
  DZ: 143563,
  AO: 143564,
  AI: 143538,
  AR: 143505,
  AM: 143524,
  AU: 143460,
  AT: 143445,
  AZ: 143568,
  BH: 143559,
  BB: 143541,
  BY: 143565,
  BE: 143446,
  BZ: 143555,
  BM: 143542,
  BO: 143556,
  BW: 143525,
  BR: 143503,
  VG: 143543,
  BN: 143560,
  BG: 143526,
  CA: 143455,
  KY: 143544,
  CL: 143483,
  CN: 143465,
  CO: 143501,
  CR: 143495,
  HR: 143494,
  CY: 143557,
  CZ: 143489,
  DK: 143458,
  DM: 143545,
  EC: 143509,
  EG: 143516,
  SV: 143506,
  EE: 143518,
  FI: 143447,
  FR: 143442,
  DE: 143443,
  GH: 143573,
  GR: 143448,
  GD: 143546,
  GT: 143504,
  GY: 143553,
  HN: 143510,
  HK: 143463,
  HU: 143482,
  IS: 143558,
  IN: 143467,
  ID: 143476,
  IE: 143449,
  IL: 143491,
  IT: 143450,
  JM: 143511,
  JP: 143462,
  JO: 143528,
  KE: 143529,
  KW: 143493,
  LV: 143519,
  LB: 143497,
  LT: 143520,
  LU: 143451,
  MO: 143515,
  MK: 143530,
  MG: 143531,
  MY: 143473,
  ML: 143532,
  MT: 143521,
  MU: 143533,
  MX: 143468,
  MS: 143547,
  NP: 143484,
  NL: 143452,
  NZ: 143461,
  NI: 143512,
  NE: 143534,
  NG: 143561,
  NO: 143457,
  OM: 143562,
  PK: 143477,
  PA: 143485,
  PY: 143513,
  PE: 143507,
  PH: 143474,
  PL: 143478,
  PT: 143453,
  QA: 143498,
  RO: 143487,
  RU: 143469,
  SA: 143479,
  SN: 143535,
  SG: 143464,
  SK: 143496,
  SI: 143499,
  ZA: 143472,
  ES: 143454,
  LK: 143486,
  SR: 143554,
  SE: 143456,
  CH: 143459,
  TW: 143470,
  TZ: 143572,
  TH: 143475,
  TN: 143536,
  TR: 143480,
  UG: 143537,
  UA: 143492,
  AE: 143481,
  US: 143441,
  UY: 143514,
  UZ: 143566,
  VE: 143502,
  VN: 143471,
  YE: 143571
}
```

Comment: Amazing insight! What do those platform-ids mean? Are those for iPod, iPhone, iPad etc?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 5):

A (small) update on this one:

X-Apple-Store-Front work with ID's in this order:

`<country>-<language*>,<platform>`
Where language is optional. Default is EN-US.

Example: `143452-10,9` (-Dutch,Apps)

Here's an updated list of country codes:

```
'AE' => '143481',
'AF' => '143610',
'AG' => '143540',
'AI' => '143538',
'AL' => '143575',
'AM' => '143524',
'AO' => '143564',
'AR' => '143505',
'AT' => '143445',
'AU' => '143460',
'AZ' => '143568',
'BA' => '143612',
'BB' => '143541',
'BD' => '143490',
'BE' => '143446',
'BF' => '143578',
'BG' => '143526',
'BH' => '143559',
'BJ' => '143576',
'BM' => '143542',
'BN' => '143560',
'BO' => '143556',
'BR' => '143503',
'BS' => '143539',
'BT' => '143577',
'BW' => '143525',
'BY' => '143565',
'BZ' => '143555',
'CA' => '143455',
'CD' => '143613',
'CG' => '143582',
'CH' => '143459',
'CI' => '143527',
'CL' => '143483',
'CM' => '143574',
'CN' => '143465',
'CO' => '143501',
'CR' => '143495',
'CV' => '143580',
'CY' => '143557',
'CZ' => '143489',
'DE' => '143443',
'DK' => '143458',
'DM' => '143545',
'DO' => '143508',
'DZ' => '143563',
'EC' => '143509',
'EE' => '143518',
'EG' => '143516',
'ES' => '143454',
'FI' => '143447',
'FJ' => '143583',
'FM' => '143591',
'FR' => '143442',
'GA' => '143614',
'GB' => '143444',
'GD' => '143546',
'GF' => '143615',
'GH' => '143573',
'GM' => '143584',
'GR' => '143448',
'GT' => '143504',
'GW' => '143585',
'GY' => '143553',
'HK' => '143463',
'HN' => '143510',
'HR' => '143494',
'HU' => '143482',
'ID' => '143476',
'IE' => '143449',
'IL' => '143491',
'IN' => '143467',
'IQ' => '143617',
'IS' => '143558',
'IT' => '143450',
'JM' => '143511',
'JO' => '143528',
'JP' => '143462',
'KE' => '143529',
'KG' => '143586',
'KH' => '143579',
'KN' => '143548',
'KP' => '143466',
'KR' => '143466',
'KW' => '143493',
'KY' => '143544',
'KZ' => '143517',
'LA' => '143587',
'LB' => '143497',
'LC' => '143549',
'LI' => '143522',
'LK' => '143486',
'LR' => '143588',
'LT' => '143520',
'LU' => '143451',
'LV' => '143519',
'LY' => '143567',
'MA' => '143620',
'MD' => '143523',
'ME' => '143619',
'MG' => '143531',
'MK' => '143530',
'ML' => '143532',
'MM' => '143570',
'MN' => '143592',
'MO' => '143515',
'MR' => '143590',
'MS' => '143547',
'MT' => '143521',
'MU' => '143533',
'MV' => '143488',
'MW' => '143589',
'MX' => '143468',
'MY' => '143473',
'MZ' => '143593',
'NA' => '143594',
'NE' => '143534',
'NG' => '143561',
'NI' => '143512',
'NL' => '143452',
'NO' => '143457',
'NP' => '143484',
'NR' => '143606',
'NZ' => '143461',
'OM' => '143562',
'PA' => '143485',
'PE' => '143507',
'PG' => '143597',
'PH' => '143474',
'PK' => '143477',
'PL' => '143478',
'PT' => '143453',
'PW' => '143595',
'PY' => '143513',
'QA' => '143498',
'RO' => '143487',
'RS' => '143500',
'RU' => '143469',
'RW' => '143621',
'SA' => '143479',
'SB' => '143601',
'SC' => '143599',
'SE' => '143456',
'SG' => '143464',
'SI' => '143499',
'SK' => '143496',
'SL' => '143600',
'SN' => '143535',
'SR' => '143554',
'ST' => '143598',
'SV' => '143506',
'SZ' => '143602',
'TC' => '143552',
'TD' => '143581',
'TH' => '143475',
'TJ' => '143603',
'TM' => '143604',
'TN' => '143536',
'TO' => '143608',
'TR' => '143480',
'TT' => '143551',
'TW' => '143470',
'TZ' => '143572',
'UA' => '143492',
'UG' => '143537',
'US' => '143441',
'UY' => '143514',
'UZ' => '143566',
'VC' => '143550',
'VE' => '143502',
'VG' => '143543',
'VN' => '143471',
'VU' => '143609',
'XK' => '143624',
'YE' => '143571',
'ZA' => '143472',
'ZM' => '143622', 
'ZW' => '143605'
```

I haven't found a 'platform' list (yet).